# Trying to follow this interactive widget tutorial

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I'm trying to follow this interactive widget tutorial:
[Python-Data Projects — Data Analysis UI Reinforced by Ipywidgets](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-data-projects-data-analysis-ui-reinforced-by-ipywidgets-d680493464b8),
but every time I get a `No CSV loaded` error. This happens when I try to upload the csv and click on `Preview`.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
%matplotlib inline

tab = widgets.Tab()    
out = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
up = widgets.FileUpload(accept="", multiple=False)
delim = widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=[';', ',', ' '],
    description='Separator: ',
    disabled=False)
eraser = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=['tab','"'],
    value=['tab'],
    #rows=10,
    description='Eraser: ',
    disabled=False)
rows = widgets.IntSlider(
    value=0,
    step=1,
    description='# of lines:',
    disabled=False,
    continuous_update=False,
    orientation='horizontal',
    readout=True,
    readout_format='d')
button_upload = widgets.Button(
    description='Upload',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='warning',
    tooltip='Click to Upload',
    icon='check')
button_preview = widgets.Button(
    description='Preview',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='info',
    tooltip='Click to Preview',
    icon='search')
button_plot = widgets.Button(
    description='Plot',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='danger',
    tooltip='Click to Plot',
    icon='pencil')
graph_type = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['Bar Chart', 'Line Chart'],
    value='Bar Chart',
    description='Chart Type:',
    disabled=False)
x_axis = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=[''],
    value='',
    description='X-Axis:',
    disabled=False)
y_axis = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=[''],
    value='',
    description='Y-Axis:',
    disabled=False)
color_picker = widgets.ColorPicker(
    concise=False,
    description='Color Picker: ',
    value='lightblue',
    disabled=False)
toggle = widgets.ToggleButtons(
    options=['Preview  ', 'Info  ', 'Stats  '],
    description='Options',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='warning',
    icons=['search', 'info', 'tachometer'])
accordion = widgets.Accordion(children=[
    up, 
    widgets.VBox([delim, eraser]), 
    rows])
accordion.set_title(0, 'File Selection')
accordion.set_title(1, 'Delimiter')
accordion.set_title(2, 'Skip Rows')
accordion_box = widgets.VBox([
    accordion, 
    widgets.HBox([button_preview, button_upload]),
    out
])
children = [
    accordion_box, 
    widgets.VBox([toggle, out]),
    widgets.VBox([
        widgets.HBox([graph_type, color_picker]),
        widgets.HBox([x_axis, y_axis]), 
        button_plot,
        out
])]
tab.children = children
tab.set_title(0, "Upload")
tab.set_title(1, "Describer")
tab.set_title(2, "Plotter")
display(tab)
def content_parser():
    if up.value == {}:
        with out:
            print('No CSV loaded')    
    else:
        typ, content = "", ""
        up_value = up.value
        for i in up_value.keys():
            typ = up_value[i]["metadata"]["type"]
            
        if typ == "text/csv":
            content = up_value[i]["content"]
            content_str = str(content, 'utf-8')
    
            if eraser.value != {}: 
                for val in eraser.value:
                    if val == "tab":
                        content_str = content_str.replace("\t","")
                    else:
                        content_str = content_str.replace(val,"")
            if content_str != "":
                str_io = StringIO(content_str) 
                return str_io
def df_converter():
    content = content_parser()
    if content is not None:
        df = pd.read_csv(content, sep=delim.value, index_col=False, skiprows=rows.value)    
        return df
    else:
        return None
def preview():
    df = df_converter()
    with out:
        out.clear_output()
        print('\n -----Now this is how your DF looks like:----- \n')
        if df is not None:
            print(df.head(10))
        else:
            print('Configuration is wrong/missing...')
def upload():
    df = df_converter()
    with out:
        out.clear_output()
        print('\n --------Your uploaded DF looks like:-------- \n')
        if df is not None:
            print(df)
            x_axis.options = df.columns
            y_axis.options = df.columns
        else:
            print('Configuration is wrong/missing...')
def desc():
    info_level = toggle.value
    if info_level != {}:
        df = df_converter()
        with out:
            out.clear_output()
            print('\n ------Your {} looks like:------ \n'.format(
                info_level))
            if df is not None:
                if info_level == 'Info  ':
                    print(df.info(verbose=True))
                elif info_level == 'Stats  ':
                    print(df.describe())
                elif info_level == 'Preview  ':
                    print(df.head(5))
                else:
                    print('Configuration is wrong/missing...')
    
    
def plot():
    graph = graph_type.value
    if graph != {}:
        df = df_converter()
        with out:
            out.clear_output()
            print('\n ------Your {} looks like:------ \n'.format(
                graph))
            if (df is not None):
                df = df.head(5)
                height = df[y_axis.value]
                bars = df[x_axis.value]
                y_pos = np.arange(len(height))
                plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
                if graph == 'Bar Chart':
                    plt.bar(
                        y_pos, 
                        height, 
                        color=color_picker.value)
                    plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)
                elif graph == 'Line Chart':
                    plt.plot(
                        bars,
                        height, 
                        color=color_picker.value,
                        marker='o', 
                        linestyle='solid'
                    )
                    plt.xticks(bars)
                plt.show()
                
def preview_clicked(b):
    preview()
def upload_clicked(b):
    upload()
def desc_clicked(b):
    desc()
def plotter_clicked(b):
    plot()
    
button_preview.on_click(preview_clicked)
button_upload.on_click(upload_clicked)
toggle.observe(desc_clicked, 'value')
button_plot.on_click(plotter_clicked)
```

Comment: This seems to work fine to me, which versions of ipywidgets are you running?

Comment: I'm using version 7.5.1

Comment: The code runs, however, when I upload the csv and click on 'Preview', it returns that 'Configuration is wrong/missing...'

Comment: Are you definitely loading a csv file? If the `if typ == "text/csv":` check fails, you might get that behaviour.

Comment: Yes I am loading a csv file

Comment: Can you share the file? Will the file open property with excel/pandas?